# How can I find elements with attributes within a list?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

How can I find the elements with different attributes with lxml on python ?

for example

```
<Form>
    <Subform ind="0">
        <Check ind="0">0</Check>
        <Check ind="1">1</Check>
        <Check ind="2">2</Check>
        <Check ind="3">3</Check>
    </Subform>
</Form>
```

to retrieve the Checks I do:

```
tree.findall("./Form/Subform/Check")
```

to get the first:

```
tree.findall("./Form/Subform/Check[@ind='0']")
```

but what I want to do is something like

```
tree.findall("./Form/Subform/Check[@ind='0' or @ind='1']")
```

To retrieve the first and second only (or first and last)

How can I do that with lxml ?

Comment: Don't think this was a duplicate of that question - it's just findall vs xpath question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression is correct but you need to use `xpath()` method which provide full XPath 1.0 support. `findall()` only support limited subset of XPath as `xml.etree.ElementTree` does :

```
tree.xpath("/Form/Subform/Check[@ind='0' or @ind='1']")
```

Answer (score 1):

> `tree.findall("./Form/Subform/Check[@ind='0' or @ind='1']")`

The expression is valid and this will work in `lxml` with `xpath()` method. If you want to make it "scalable", you can *dynamically construct the expression*:

```
values = ["0", "1"]
condition = " or ".join("@ind = '%s'" % value for value in values)
print(root.xpath("//Subform/Check[%s]" % condition))
```